# Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr in table

Tags: tables

What is wrong with this table, please?
It is giving an error Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr
Where is the mistake in the number of &?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{multirow, tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\small
\caption{Comparison}
\label{comp}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{cccc|cccc}
\hline\hline\noalign{\smallskip}

\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{A}} &&&& \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{B}} &&&\\

\hline
 
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two serious issues with the table.

- First, the `tabularx` environment is defined to have 8 columns, yet the instruction

  ```
  \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{A}} &&&& \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{B}} &&& \\
  ```

  requires the table to be defined as having 14 [!] columns. If the table is meant to have just 8 columns, you should probably write

  ```
  \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{A}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{B}} \\
  ```

  That's the immediate cause of the -- admittedly somewhat cryptic -- message "Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr".
- Second, employing a `tabularx` environment makes no sense unless you actually employ the `X` column type for at least one of the columns. If you intend to employ a centered version of the `X` type for all 8 columns, I suggest using the following code

  ```
  %% in the preamble:
  \usepackage{tabularx}
  \newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
  ...
  %% in the body of document:
  \begin{table}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{CCCC|CCCC}
  \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{A}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{B}} \\
  \hline
  ...
  \end{tabularx}
  \end{table}
  ```

Comment: To be a bit more explicit: `\multicol{4}...` means that you should omit 4-1 `&` symbols from this row.

Comment: @Teepeemm - Nicely put!